# Hyper-V Virtual Switch overrides the default Ethernet adapter

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v-manager

I'm trying to create a new external virtual switch in the Hyper-V manager.

When I do that, my network stops working properly. It seems that when the virtual switch is created, it copies *some* of the IP v4 properties from my Ethernet adapter, and then disables IP (v4 and v6) on my Ethernet adapter.

My computer then has no choice but to use the new virtual adapter, which isn't properly configured (specifically, the DNS addresses aren't copied over. I'm using static IP and DNSes).

I can fix the IP v4 properties in the virtual switch, but why does Hyper-V even do that? And more importantly, how can I make it stop doing that. I'd like my network to keep working properly after creating a virtual switch.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but ultimately is your question simply *"...but why does Hyper-V even do that?"*

Comment: So sorry! Submitted the question two sentences too early...

Comment: No worries!  It happens to the best of us, and your post is much more clear now.  Personally, I am using DHCP on my home network and haven't encountered similar problems when I create a Hyper-V virtual switch.  It sounds like the underlying problem is that the virtual switch does take over the IP address duties, but ignores the static DNS server entries.  Ultimately, the circumstances surrounding this entire scenario are very uncommon.  It isn't too surprising that you need to re-enter your static DNS addresses.  Essentially, it's much like configuring a new router.

Comment: Hyper-V does this to create the Virtual Switch you need for your VMs. Hyper-V is different from VMware Workstation and VirtualBox which are type 2 hypervisors, as it's a type 1 hypervisor and works below your Windows OS.  When you install Hyper-V what it's essentially doing is moving your whole Windows OS into a special virtual machine and is making the necessary modifications most users need to run Windows and other OSes in VMs.